# Notation for partial function set.

Tags: functions, notation

There is a standard notation for the set of all functions between $S$ and $T$, namely $T^S$. Is there a similar notation for the set of all partial functions between $S$ and $T$?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: In some sense, $(T + 1)^S$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Wow. By itself, this is a *very* useless comment, but it probably carries some weight because you know a lot of mathematics and are into logic and set theory.

Comment: What do you mean, @Zhen?

Comment: @Student There is a natural bijection between $(T + 1)^S$ and the set of partial functions $S \rightharpoonup T$. Or you can just count.

Comment: We define $T^S$ to be the set of functions from $S$ to $T$. Thus $(T+1)^S$ is the set of functions from $S$ to the set of ordinality $|T|+1$... Would you make the said bijection explicit, @Zhen?

Comment: Take a partial function and turn it into a total function by sending elements outside the domain to the new element.

Comment: Possibly the set $T^{<S}$ can be seen that way, and @Asaf should be able to tell if I am wrong.

Comment: @Student: No, for example $T=S=\omega$ then $\omega^{<\omega}$ denotes only finite functions from an initial segment, not partial functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't call this "standard", but I like this notation for the set of all partial maps from $X$ to $Y$, from Davey and Priestley's *Introduction to Lattices and Order*:

$$(X \multimap \mspace{-2mu} \to Y)$$

In LaTeX:

```
(X \multimap \mspace{-2mu} \to Y)
```

Update (2018-09-25): I've decided that I don't like the above notation after all. May I suggest $Y^{\subseteq X}$ for the set of all partial functions? This nicely complements $Y^X$ and $Y^{(X)}$ (the set of all finitely supported functions). Also, from Duistermaat and Kolk's *Multidimensional Real Analysis I*: $f : X \supset\!\to Y$ means $f$ is a partial function from $X$ to $Y$ (actually, the authors use this to denote a total function from some subset of $X$ into $Y$, when they don't want to explicitly specify the domain). I like this because the "$\supset$" part of the symbol suggests that $X$ is a superset of something.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest the notation

$$ A \rightharpoonup B = \bigcup_{C \subseteq A} (C \rightarrow B) $$

where $\rightharpoonup$ is `\rightharpoonup` in TeX. A [Google Scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=rightharpoonup+%22partial+function%22) yields many results using this notation for partial functions.

Comment: I like this notation: $A \rightharpoonup B$. Can anyoneone point to a reference where this notation is used?

Comment: @balage See the link I added to the answer.

Comment: thank you, this is really helpful.

Comment: I remember taking a graduate seminar on algorithms and partial functions with Moschovakis in the early 1990s where he was using the notation $\rightharpoonup$

Answer (score 0):

Z-notation uses this: ⇸ (\char"21F8 in latex)

See, e.g., http://staff.washington.edu/jon/z-lectures/structure.html

How? Just add this:

```
% Partial function character from Z-notation
\newcommand\pfun{\mathrel{\ooalign{\hfil$\mapstochar$\hfil\cr$\to$\cr}}}
```